# Entity Framework Join with Group by select columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have 2 tables that I am trying to left join with a linq query

I want to left join 2 tables, i want to group multiple columns but I want to select specific columns and use datepart etc on some of the columns where applicable. I seem to be able to select columns no issue but then I add a grouping in there and It doesn't work.

```
var data = from p in context.tablea 
join s in context.tableb
on new
{ p.id,
  p.name
}
equals
new
{
  s.id,
  s.name
}
 group p by new
{
 p.name
 p.type
 } into x
 Select new
 {
   p.columnA, p.columnB, s.columa, 
   s.date.value.Month
  }
```

It is telling me that p or s does not exist in the current context.

But I can select any column if I take the group by statement out.

Any example I see with group by seems to have a key in the select new followed by a sum or count but I want to select columns as above, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The output consists of 4 columns from `tablea` and `tableb`. The grouping seems to be at odds with the desired result, for which IMO one simple join would suffice. How would you do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add multiple entries into groups with `group new { p, s }` and get the first value from the group in the `select` statement.

```cs
var data = from p in context.tablea 
    join s in context.tableb 
        on new { p.id, p.name } equals new { s.id, s.name } into ps
    from s in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { p, s } by new { p.name, p.type } into x
    select new
    {
        ColumnA = x.First().p.columnA, 
        ColumnB = x.First().p.columnB, 
        Columa = x.First().s != null
            ? x.First().s.columa
            : null, 
        Month = x.First().s != null 
            ? x.First().s.date.value.Month
            : (int?)null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how LINQ works. The `into` clause, known as the query continuation clause, indicates the end of the proceeding scope. In this case, the data has changed shape such that the range variable is then enumerating the groups.

This isn't a limitation as you can continue to do introduce subsequent clauses. In this case however, what you actually want to do is perform the projection of the elements you are grouping in the `group..by` clause instead of using `into`.

```
var data = from p in context.tablea 
           join s in context.tableb 
           on new { p.id, p.name } equals new { s.id, s.name }
           group new
           {
               p.columnA,
               p.columnB,
               s.columa, 
               s.date.value.Month
           }
           by new 
           {
               p.name,
               p.type
           };
```

This results in each group's elements having the desired form. One of the beautiful things about LINQ is that you can project truly nested hierarchies and trees instead of having to flatten every group with an aggregate function.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if that will work. Essentially looking for a.                    
                                                                     select p.x, p.y s.a from tablea p left join tableb s on p.id. = s.id group by p.x, p.y . I am struggling to see the selection of columns on that query unless I am reading it wrong?

Comment: Well, it seemed to be what you were trying to achieve. The problem description and the range variables you are using indicated that you wanted to transform the grouped elements.

Comment: If you wanted a left join you should have said so. A left join is a bit different and what you had was an inner join. You indicated problems in a different area of the query.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear enough. What would be an alternative?

Comment: Just clarify the question by editing it. Explain what you're trying to achieve. The issue you stated was that you were getting an error that the range variables weren't in scope. You received two answers that dealt with that in different ways. I think mine's better but neither of the answers are now applicable because you have a different problem than the one you stated

Comment: Included the left join query detail. I can select columns without grouping clause but when i try grouping I have no way of selecting columns

Comment: @Brian what you want is a group join i believe. Remember, this isn't SQL it's LINQ and, while they share some concepts, they are fundamentally different. In LINQ, a group join pairs of each item in the LHS with a sequence of all correlated matching values in the RHS. It results in a sequence of (L, Rs) which you can further query.

Comment: for some of the examples of left joins it is using the join keyword. I haven't come across a groupjoin example for this yet. The issue is when i include a groupby clause in my linq query it causes issues eith selecting specific columns. Wondering have you something that might work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Group join is the name of the operation. The query expression syntax is `from x in xs join y in ys on key(x) equals key(y) into joinedYs  select whatever`. If you use method syntax, the method is named `Queryable.GroupJoin`